# If many EM signals exist in same time/place, when would interference occur?

Tags: signal, communication, electromagnetic

If electromagnetic waves can experience interference from same or different frequency transmitters in surrounding region; Then why do we not experience interference when many people use their mobile phones at once in the same place?

This is the part I don't understand. 
Is it to do with phase?

EDIT - Thank you everyone for your answer. I did read on Frequency Hopping, but my issue is in trying to "envision" what happens. I attached a pic of what's in my mind. If 2 Transmitters transmit waves... they "may" (and certainly will in far field) cross each other. Do the red circles not pose interference even if amplitude or frequency is different via spread spectrum? Or I'm missing something? Can the 2 waves ever end up being in Superposition even if they hopped frequency?  [image]

Comment: Maybe someone will write a good answer. In the mean time, you may want to read up on frequency hopping and spread spectrum and orthogonal codes. See if you can find good explanations of those things.

Comment: Superposition definitely happens. Interference, in the strict technical sense, is unavoidable. But because both transmitters are constantly changing frequency, the interference nodes and anti-nodes move around in space in unpredictable ways. Because the codes are chosen with care (this is where orthogonality comes in), the net effect of this interference is degradation of signal to noise ratio (SNR). As more transmitters go online, the SNR for all channels goes down. But they are still able to communicate.

Comment: You probably shouldn't take those "wave" diagrams too literally.  When a transmitter is on, the radiated energy is a continuous field, and the area of potential interference is *everywhere* that the signal is strong enough to be received.  If the two transmitters are on different frequencies, the receivers have narrow filters that can select the desired signal.  Random frequency hopping may create some conflicts, but practical frequency-hopping is synchronized.  Spread-Spectrum uses a common frequency, but the coding used is designed to not interfere.  You should study this, it's interesting

Comment: @PaulElliott, for CW transmitters, those interference patterns are very important and determine the locations of nulls, where no signal can be picked up. This can happen in the real world due to reflections. Sometimes moving an inch or two will make a huge difference for a UHF radio. This is because you move from the anti-node to the node.

Comment: Thank you mkeith and PaulElliott for your insights and explanations. I will go delve more into Spread Spectrum Coding techniques to get a better understanding.

Comment: @mkeith, I suppose you are talking about Fresnel zones?  Yes, these can have deep nulls, but I don't think that's what that drawing was showing.  I took it for a more general "here are radio waves" drawing.  Fresnel zones aren't equally spaced.

Comment: I took it to be the standard drawing always used in physics class to depict interference patterns from two coherent sources.

Comment: I guess we would have to ask!  But the real-world signals are unlikely to be coherent, and the frequencies will be off by some fraction of a ppm due to typical oscillator inaccuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they were all on the same frequency, at the same time, and using the same modulation scheme, then yes, there would be interference.  But cellphones (and other services) use methods like multiple frequency channels, timeslots and "Code Division Multiplexing", also known as "Spread Spectrum".  These techniques allow many transmitters to share the same frequency band.

In general terms, phase has little to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Older cellphones used a band for the basestations to transmit out to the customers, and a 2nd band was used by all the customers transmitting back to the basestations. These bands, in the 900MHz region, were 20 or 30 Megahertz wide, supporting hundreds of 30KHz narrow-band FM cell signals.

The basestations used expensive band-pass filters to keep their 50watt outgoing signal power OUT of the incoming millipico (femto) watt basestation receiver circuits. The receiver signal floor is computed at -174dBm + 10*log10(30KHz), or -174+45 = -129 dBm; with 0dBm being 1milliWatt into 50 Ohms or 0.632 vPP, the -129dBm floor is 0.632 / [120dB + 10dB -1dB]= 0.632 / [10^6 * (3.16/1.12)] = 0.25microVoltsPP. The 50 watt outgoing power, needed for the users the most distance away from the basestation, would easily *INTERFER* and probably destroy the receiver circuits located only a few feet away inside those little houses at the ground level, unless the bandpass filters were used.

Answer (score 0):

The waves do not affect each other. Some electronic circuits that receive several different signals at the same time can suffer if the signals are on the same frequency or on too near frequencies. Then the radio receivers that use filtering might not be a able to keep them separate.

Different signals can interfere in electronic circuits also via saturation and by that caused mixing (=radiotechnical mixer). The signals can be in different frequencies, but one of them can by the sheer power clog the circuits and that is one form of mixing.

The mobile phones do not transmit wildly all the time. The base station conducts the orchestra and never two phones send simultaneously at the same frequency until they're in the operating circles of different base stations and enoughly far away.

The phones are designed to tolerate other phones nearby without any saturation. That's not a design criteria for some cheap audio stuff and that's you surely have noticed.

Comment: In multiple access schemes, the signals DEFINITELY affect each other. As more and more channels are occupied, the SNR for all channels is degraded. If they are orthogonal, then each channel looks to all other channels like a noise source spread evenly across the band.

Comment: @mkeith the radiowaves do not affect each other altough they travel along the same space. One radiowave can affect to a piece of material  (maybe a bottle or a stone or a  cellphone) so that piece reacts differently when also another radiowave comes. But a radiowave has no effect to other radiowaves directly. All interactions need some material and the affection is something that the piece of a material does.

Comment: @user287001, while I see your point, I don't quite agree with it. You can measure the time varying electric field at any point. It will vary differently when both waves are present. You could say that in some technical sense, they don't affect each other, since they continue on exactly the same, but given the context of the OP's question as one about interference, I really don't think that is the right way to look at it.

Comment: What about beamforming? Isn't that literally done by having waves constructively and destructively interfere in space?

Comment: @AndrejaKo the beam that seems to be formed by independent sources that accidentally happen to be in sync exists only as a pattern of resultant field strengths. Even you will calculate it having waves that propagate without disturbing each other. To have a really directed beam the sources (=made of some material) interact with each other via the nearfields.

Comment: @AndrejaKo unless you are dealing with a non-linear medium, the waves themselves do not really interfere.  If you measure at a point in space where both are present you will see the sum, and that may *effectively* be interference, but if you move to another point to measure where only one is present then that is all you will see - even if you are measuring the wave after it has seemingly "passed through" another.  Think about intersecting beams of colored light - a piece of paper held where they cross will show the combined color but further out on each you will again see it alone.